# How to turn a colum of integer data "2018-08-2" into a string and then compare it to a list of string elements in groovy

Tags: groovy

So I have a long list of dates that have to be compared to 2 different dates and right now im using:

```
if ((StartDate<=${Day}) && (${Day}<=EndDate))
   return 1
else
  return 0
```

for function day and

```
if ((StartDate<=${Day}) && (${Day}<=EndDate))
   return 2
else
  return 0
```

for function Func2

and when i try to run it, it prints me out an error :

> " Failed to transform value 10-08-2018 of column StartDate in function
>   Day: Failed to convert value 10-08-2018 in column StartDate to type
>   class java.lang.Integer "

any ideas how to fix it? I am a newbe at Groovy.

I know that I recently asked a similar question but it was not anwsered fully, because it still prints out the same error.

Comment: You must need to covert your String format date into the Date type to compare the two dates, dates can not be compared in a String format and the date you are saying that it is in Integer format "18-08-02" is invalid Integer, please understand the basics.

Comment: Ansis, the parts of code, you've provided is not really groovy. Please edit your question and give more information: run-able code, full error message, better with stacktrace,...